# What is the meaning of "any" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, grammaticality-in-context

But, if the city were not to be besieged, what course could with any prudence be adopted?

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Comment: What problem are you having - `any` isn't being used in an unusual way, as far as I can see?

Answer (score 1):

"Any" normally means "some" or "more than nothing". If someone asks, "Is there any water left in the bottle?" he means, is the amount of water left in the bottle more than zero.

And that's exactly the meaning here. What course would you adopt if you had ANY prudence? That is, someone with no prudence at all might adopt some different course, but assuming you have at least some, what course would you adopt?